# Need help in attempt to animate gif inside TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, animated-gif

I want to be able to load animated gifs into a Textview between text, this is what i've come up with:

I use Html.fromHtml

Since one gif can occur multiple times i make an array of all the different gifs that are loaded so that i can just pass the reference back (though in this tester that isn't used)

this is what i've got so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ImageGetter {
    private TextView mTv;
    private Map<String, LevelListDrawable> gifs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gifs = new HashMap<>();
        String imgs="<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://lonelytraveller.comoj.com/qff/tjatja.gif\" style=\"height:50px; width:100px\" />Test Article, Test Article, Test Article, Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,Test Article,v</p>";
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(imgs, this, null);
        mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        mTv.setText(spanned);

    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        if(gifs.get(source.split("\\Q/\\E")[source.split("\\Q/\\E").length-1]) != null){
            return gifs.get(source.split("\\Q/\\E")[source.split("\\Q/\\E").length-1]);
        }else {
            LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
            Drawable empty = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.save);
            d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

            new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

            return d;
        }
    }

    class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, byte[]> {

        private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;
        private String key;
        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String source = (String) params[0];
            key = source.split("\\Q/\\E")[source.split("\\Q/\\E").length-1];
            mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
            try {
                InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
                return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            if(bytes != null) {
                GifDecoder decoder = new GifDecoder();
                decoder.read(bytes);
                ArrayList<Long> alist = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < decoder.getFrameCount(); i++) {
                    decoder.advance();
                    Bitmap bitmap = decoder.getNextFrame();
                    BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    int i2 = i+1;
                    mDrawable.addLevel(i2, i2, d);
                    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                    alist.add((long) decoder.getNextDelay());
                }
                gifs.put(key, mDrawable);
                animateGif(decoder.getFrameCount(), mDrawable, alist);
            }
        }
    }
    public void animateGif(int length, LevelListDrawable d, ArrayList<Long> delays){
        for(int i = 1; i<(length+1); i++){
            d.setLevel(i);

            CharSequence t = mTv.getText();
            mTv.setText(t);

            long sleep = delays.get(i-1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(i == length) i=1;
        }
    }
}
```

I use this GifDecoder: https://gist.github.com/devunwired/4479231

With the code i posted above, i only get the empty drawable (level 0) if i put a log in animateGif function i can see he does do the infinite loop, but it just doesn't work it stays at the empty drawable image;

If i change the onPostExecute function's content with:

```
    if(bytes != null) {
        GifDecoder decoder = new GifDecoder();
        decoder.read(bytes);
        decoder.advance();
        Bitmap bitmap = decoder.getNextFrame();
        BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
        mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        mDrawable.setLevel(1);

        CharSequence t = mTv.getText();
        mTv.setText(t);
    }
```

It does change the empty image into the first frame of the gif file.
I just can't see why this wouldn't work, can anyone help me?

Comment: A debugger can help you. The lib author can maybe help you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to some help from jawatio at android-dev irc..

By adding this dependancy to the build.gradle file:

compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'

Which is from: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

And then doing something like this:

```
public class test extends Activity implements Drawable.Callback {

 public TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testtext);
        new LoadImage().execute("http://lonelytraveller.comoj.com/qff/tjatja.gif");

    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        tv.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
        tv.postDelayed(what, when);
    }

    @Override
    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
        tv.removeCallbacks(what);
    }


    class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, byte[]> {

        private String key;
        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String source = (String) params[0];
            //key = source.split("\\Q/\\E")[source.split("\\Q/\\E").length-1];
            try {
                InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
                return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] b) {
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("test");
            GifDrawable gd = null;
            try {
                gd = new GifDrawable(b);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (gd != null) {
                gd.setBounds(0, 0, gd.getIntrinsicWidth(), gd.getIntrinsicHeight());

                gd.setCallback(test.this);

                ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(gd), 1, 2, 0);
                tv.setText(ssb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```